# how to add a message (memo / sticky note) on (top of existing) html page

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

How do I achieve this: 
I have an HTML5 homepage and want to give the visitors a message (e.g. "dear visitor, I am on vacation from....") in the form of a memo/sticky note e.g. in the top right corner of the home page. Is there a neat and nice solution to have it "just" on top of the existing UI. Other ideas are welcome.
thx

Comment: pls post your code, a fiddle is better

Comment: Add a div!! Keep its position fixed top 0!! Thats it..

Comment: well, don't know if that's very helpful. I used an html5up template like this: https://jsfiddle.net/tn3ha1tf/ (of course without the styles here)

Comment: Guruprasad's comment is helpful. You will need to add some sort of element to the page to display the content you want to add *"dear visitor, I am on vacation from"*. Using css you can position it to fixed and top.

Comment: thanks for the comments! of course, the comment is helpful (I thought it was not helpful that I include code for a simple html page - since the solution to this is not related to a specific page) :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out this jsfiddle for a simple example
https://jsfiddle.net/traso7o7/

`position: absolute;` is main thing you need to put your message on the top

Answer (score 0):

```
position:absolute;
top:0;
right:0;
width:200p;
height:200px;
```

Comment: Maybe you should elaborate a bit :)